# Automatically run command after a cell is executed in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to automatically run a "post-processing" command every time a cell in jupyter notebook is executed. Is this possible?

Specifically, I'm trying to make sure all matplotlib figure references are removed after a cell is executed, to avoid the "max number of figures" warning and avoid unnecessarily storing the figure objects. I tried doing this with `%config InlineBackend.close_figures = True` but the option seems to be ignored, or perhaps I am not understanding it correctly. As a workaround I'd just like to automatically call a function that checks if matplotlib is loaded, then deletes any saved figures if they exist.